# how to resize iphone tab bar in xcode?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm developing an iOS app that has 5 items in the tab bar. But they are not evenly distributed. I want the right-most one to be larger and obviously it takes more spaces. and other 4 tab items can evenly distribute. 
I've done some research but cannot find a good solution. Where can i customize the tab bars?

thanks

Comment: resize xcode's tabbar or your iphone app's?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya sorry, rephrase question subject: resize iphone tab bar in xcode

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the standard iOS tab bar. You need to create a custom one or use one of the numerous open source libraries that do it already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html). It is highly customizable and allows to modify width of each item in it.